# How to prevent check box to un-check after form submit or page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am having problems with checkboxes, using Ruby on Rails 3.2. Check box value is normally saved into the database but when I refresh the page or click submit button on the form, check box doesn't stay checked and I don't know what am I missing here. On every refresh or submit, it gets unchecked. I would appreciate your help. Checkbox has_available_space is a boolean database value.

Database (checkbox value)

```
    create_table :user_location do |t|
      t.boolean :has_available_space
    end
```

Routes

```
    namespace :users do
       match 'update_location' => 'location#update', :via => [:post]
    end
```

Model User

```
    has_one :user_location
```

Model User Location

```
    belongs_to :user
```

Controller

```
    def update 
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     if @user.user_location.nil?
         @user.user_location = UserLocation.new
     end
     @user.user_location.has_available_space = params[:checkbox_has_available_space]
     @user.save!
     @user.user_location.save!
     redirect_to '/users/location'
    end
```

View

```
    <form id = 'location_form' action="/users/update_location" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= @user.id %>" />
       <input id = 'has_available_space' type="checkbox" name="checkbox_has_available_space" value = '<%= @user.user_location.has_available_space %>' >I have available space
    </form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473974/how-can-my-forms-checkboxes-keep-their-state-after-a-submit-and-page-reload

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the checked attribute to your checkbox element:

```
`<input type="checkbox" checked />`
```

Comment: I tried but in that case, check box is checked all the time. I need it to be checked only when I check it, and to stay checked after refresh or submit.

Comment: Yes, but surely you can set the `checked` attr as a variable from your view depending on whether you want it checked or not.

Comment: Not sure that I understand you. You mean, using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: You should be able to get the `checked` attr in your controller from the POST values and then simply print it back to the view.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see 'checked' attr between post values. I think the problem might bee deeper than that. For example, I am not sure that 'value = '<%= @user.user_location.has_available_space %>'' is ok.

Comment: If you submit with the checkbox checked, you should definitely have something like `checkbox_has_available_space=on` in your POST data.

Comment: Ok, I have that. But how do I print it back to the view?

Comment: I don't know Rails, but by the looks of things it should be something like `<input type="checkbox" <%= @checkedVariable %> />` where `@checkedVariable` is either `'checked'` if or `''` (empty string) depending on whether checked was set in the POST data.